# How to detect double click on window title in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

And of course a way to occur window movement event. Any idea?

Comment: Quite unusual for an application to react to a doubleclick on the window title. Normally this is handled by the window manager. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have several child windows in my mdi container. I want to use them as dock-able windows to make my work easier and because I don't want to make a user control to act like form. Therefore, I need to know when the title get clicked and I perform my dock action. Currently I just set it to DoubleClick but it just act in inner window area not the borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your title asks for one thing and your question is another. For your question, you are looking for this , I guess -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.move.aspx

EDIT :

Your title question -- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/MouseClickOnTitlebar.aspx

You can handle the double click by

`#define WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK              0x00A9`

Hope these answers your question.

Comment: Because they are two questions. One for title and one for movement. Thanks anyway. Any idea for title double click?

Comment: I was seeing whether unsafenativemethods can help you. looks like this is itself easy for you. handling the winform messages like stated in the link should work for you. easy enough.

Comment: left button:#define WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK              0x00A3, right button:#define WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK              0x00A6

Answer (score 3):

The solution isn't working for me (VS2015, Win7).
But a slightly different way is working...

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;    // this constant int is different

        if (m.Msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
            this.OnResizeEnd(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When the title bar of a window is double clicked the window changes in size: it either maximizes or returns to the normal window state. The Resize event is fired in these two cases and also when the window is minimized. This means that you can handle window maximize, minimize and other window resize events in this way:

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (this.WindowState)
        {
            case FormWindowState.Maximized:
                //handle maximizing
                break;
            case FormWindowState.Minimized:
                //handle minimizing
                break;
            case FormWindowState.Normal:
                //if you want, handling resizing the window in Normal state.
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

You can also handle the Move event of the form/window to do something when it moves:

```
    private void Form1_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = this.Location.ToString();
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. My form is in SizableTool state. It can't get changed in state.

Comment: You mean the FormBorderStyle is set to SizableToolWindow. A form with this border style can still be maximized, minimized, resized and moved. WindowState still *can* change. Did you try what I wrote? If not, give it a try and see for yourself. :)

Comment: Really? I thought it never get changed since I set it to SizableToolWindow. I'll try it now.

Comment: This is not a good solution as is catches all resize events, whether or not they originated in a double click on the title bar.

Comment: It doesn't change. I set Max and Min buttons to false of course. :(

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that you've set the Max and Min buttons to false. The Resize event won't get fired if you do this and double click the title bar. If you set them to true, they won't show up in the title bar since the FormBorderStyle is SizableToolWindow but you get the event fired (with the state changing). Is that an option?

Comment: @MahanGM I have answered both of your question.

user1041631 since this is not changing in size, this will not get fired up. handling the windows form message directly should be the work to do !